# Core Data Images not persisting?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am storing and creating posts with this function in my view controller:

```
@objc func createPost(){
        guard let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
        }
        let managedContext =
            appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let post = Post(context: managedContext)

        var mediaURI: URL?
        let timeInSeconds = Int64((postDate?.timeIntervalSince1970)!)
        if isVideo == true {
            let filename = String(timeInSeconds) + ".MOV"
            FileService.uploadVideo(videoURL: pickedVideoURL, name: filename)
            post.mediaFilename = filename
        } else {
            let filename = String(timeInSeconds) + ".JPG"
            FileService.uploadImage(image: postImage, name: filename)
            post.mediaFilename = filename
        }
        var postTags:[Tag] = []

        if let tokens = tagsView.tokens() {
            for token in tokens {
                let tagFetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Tag> = Tag.fetchRequest()
                tagFetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", token.title)
                do {
                    let res = try managedContext.fetch(tagFetchRequest)
                    var tag: Tag!
                    if res.count > 0 {
                        tag = res.first
                    } else {
                        tag = Tag(context: managedContext)
                        tag.name = token.title
                        tag.mostRecentUpdate = NSDate()
                        tag.mostRecentThumbnail = postImage?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0) as NSData?
                    }
                    postTags.append(tag)
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                    return
                }
            }
        }
        for tag in postTags {
            post.addToTags(tag)
        }
        post.isVideo = isVideo!
        post.thumbnail = pickedPostThumbnail?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0) as NSData?
        post.notes = notesView.text
        post.timeStamp = postDate! as NSDate
        do {
            try managedContext.save()
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
```

I am doing a lot of stuff there, but notably, I am setting the post.thumbnail with a UIImage as NSData? and at the end I am saving the context.

So I create posts and close the app, then open it again and another view controller does this:

```
 fileprivate lazy var posts: NSFetchedResultsController<Post> = {
    let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
    let managedContext =
        appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Post> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Post")
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%@ IN self.tags", tag)
    let timeSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "timeStamp", ascending: true)
    request.sortDescriptors = [timeSort]

    let posts = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: managedContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    posts.delegate = self
    return posts
}()

override func viewDidLoad(){ 
....
do {
        try posts.performFetch()

} catch let error as NSError {
       print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
}
...
}

let post = posts.object(at: indexPath)
cell.mediaFileName = post.mediaFilename
if let data = post.thumbnail {
        print(data,"data?")
        cell.thumbnail.image = UIImage.init(data: data as Data)
    } else {
        print("couldn't find")
    }
```

This works fine the first few restarts. However soon, it starts printing ("couldn't find") and not loading the image. The other fields associated with post are still loading. This is being run on the iPhone 8 simulator that comes with Xcode.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there something about how a simulator stores images in core data that doesn't persist? Or am I misusing the managed context?

Comment: You should not store images in a core data database. If you must do so, the image should not be an attribute of your entity; it should be a separate entity with a one to one relationship. But it would be better to store your images as files.

Comment: storing them as files does seem to work. Still I wonder why they don't persist if it seems to work at least initially. And is there an official apple statement on this?

Comment: What I said _is_ from the official statement.

Comment: See e.g. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Performance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH25-SW11